# PyMongo doesn't work properly with Scrapy

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

My Scrapy parser uses PyMongo as a driver for writing items to MongoDB.
To generate Requests, parser gets all records from DB and yields through:

```
...

for link in db.links.find():
    yield Request(...)

...
```

The problem is that from 800+k records it goes through only for about 6-8k. How can i iterate all 800+k records?

Comment: So, the loop goes 800+k times, but you see only 6-8k requests going, right?

Comment: It was my first idea why it doesn't work properly, so i started to log every iteration. And forloop goes only 6-8k times.

Comment: Ok, what does `db.links.find().count()` return?

Comment: db.links.find().count() # => 728010

Comment: That's strange. Can you check the same cursor loop outside of scrapy? Is it still iterating only 6-8k? Every time loop count is different, right?

Comment: The most interesting part is that when i remove `yield Request(...)` it works well - goes through all recrods. But when i insert `yield Request(...)` back - it goes only for 6-8k records.

Comment: Ok, then, couple ideas. Can you set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to smth like `0.5` and check if it goes more than 6-8k times? Then, try to increase `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting and check loop count too.

Comment: It's better now - about 50k, but still not all records.

Comment: Ok, what if you increase `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` more, to smth like 2, or 3. The problem is in the amount of requests you are trying to send, it's to big for scrapy to handle. May be increasing `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` may help too.

Comment: Have you tried getting the list from the cursor?

`for link in list(db.links.find()):`. I think you should to iterate the cursor before to create a generator using `yield`.

Comment: DB has more than 800k records, and you think that converting cursor with ALL records to list is a good idea? :)

Comment: @dimazubrik do you have any positive results with tweaking scrapy settings?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the large number of documents, would then be better if you could do the same process per page using skip/limit.

Comment: @alecxe, actually - not, because timeout makes crawler very slow. ;( I increased concurrent requests and splited find() with .skip and .limit so far.